# Can't Pass Enum Value to Recursive Template (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, enums

Suppose I want to write a recursive template function that compares an individual value to every single element in an n-dimensional vector, returning true if there is at least one match and false if there are none.

I wrote some code to do this, although it's probably far from optimal:

```
template <typename T, typename Checker>
void check_for_each(const T& v, const Checker condition)
{
  condition(v);
}

template <typename T, typename Checker>
void check_for_each(const std::vector<T>& v, const Checker condition)
{
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
  {
    check_for_each(v[i], condition);
  }
}

template <typename T, typename U>
bool is_equal_any(const T& VALUE, const std::vector<typename U> VECTOR)
{
  bool is_equal = false;
  check_for_each(VECTOR, [&is_equal, &VALUE](const T& val)
  {
    if(!is_equal && VALUE == val)
    {
      is_equal = true;
    }
  });
  return is_equal;
}
```

While this seems to work, I've encountered an unusual issue and I can't quite understand it.  For example, the following code works:

```
enum PIECE_NAME {EMPTY, PAWN, ROOK, KNIGHT, BISHOP, QUEEN, KING};
std::vector<std::vector<int>> board {{ROOK, BISHOP}, {KNIGHT, QUEEN}};
std::cout << is_equal_any(2, board); // outputs 1 (there is a rook on the board)
```

Yet the following, slight change does not:

```
std::cout << is_equal_any(ROOK, board); // compile error C2664
```

Apparently my function cannot figure out how to convert the enum value to an integer.  Of course, I can just use `static_cast<int>(ROOK)`, and the code compiles and runs as expected, but that's obviously not ideal.  Furthermore, I know that I can change my board's declaration to `std::vector<std::vector<PIECE_NAME>> board`, (which also runs as expected) but I'd prefer to leave it at `int`.   **So is it possible to rewrite these recursive template functions so that `is_equal_any` can take enum values directly?**  I'm still very new to C++, so I would really appreciate as much detail in your answer as possible.  Thank you.

Comment: Why not write a function that statically casts it and returns it for you?

Comment: Just wanted to say that you should really not be writing that kind of code. Nor passing vectors by value. Nor taking containers instead of iterators.

Comment: Can you add the verbatim error text please, not everyone uses MSVC or even if so remembers all of the error numbers.

Comment: could we please see a complete listing of your program?  remember that identifiers in an ENUM are stored in memory as integers.   Passing one of those identifiers by its "name" is probably not going to result in what you think...it doesn't mean anything to the compiler.  It definitely doesn't mean '2'...I suspect that you need to create an array using your ENUM identifiers and then assign them the value that you want to pass........exampleenum[ROOK] = 2; and then pass ROOK.  Give us your full program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises from the type `T` here:

```
check_for_each(VECTOR, [&is_equal, &VALUE](const T& val)
                                                 ^
```

By calling

```
is_equal_any(ROOK, board)
```

`T` is a `PIECE_NAME`, but what you are finally passing as parameter to this lambda are the elements of your vector of type `int`. But an `int` can't be implicitly converted to an enum.

You can't either use directly `U` as it could be a `std::vector<int>` or `std::vector< std::vector<int> >` or...

If you were using C++14, you could use a [generic lambda](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#generic-lambdas) with `auto`:

```
check_for_each(VECTOR, [&is_equal, &VALUE](const auto& val)
```

But as you tagged your question C++11, you can use a trait:

```
template <typename T>
struct leaf_type {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct leaf_type<std::vector<T>> {
    using type = typename leaf_type<T>::type;
};

template <typename T>
using leaf_type_t = typename leaf_type<T>::type;
```

usage:

```
check_for_each(VECTOR, [&is_equal, &VALUE](const leaf_type_t<U> & val)
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ff1295352bc8e23)

Btw you should avoid nested `std::vector`s and linearize it into a single one like:

```
std::vector<int> board {ROOK, BISHOP, KNIGHT, QUEEN};
```

Then you can easily use [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of an XY problem, as there are better approaches:

- Use a scoped enum

  - don't mix integers and enums
- delegate your work to [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

For example:

```
namespace multi_dim{
    template< class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate >
    bool any_of(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
    {
       using std::any_of;
       for(;first != last; ++first)
       {
          bool next = any_of(first->cbegin(), first->cend(), p);
          if (next)
             return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
}
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/J7vfZZbIInqVA3kW)

A test:

```
 std::vector<std::vector<PIECE>> board {{PIECE::ROOK, PIECE::BISHOP}, {PIECE::KNIGHT, PIECE::QUEEN}};
 std::cout << std::boolalpha << multi_dim::any_of(board.cbegin(), board.cend(), [](PIECE p){return p == PIECE::ROOK;}) << std::endl;
 std::cout << std::boolalpha << multi_dim::any_of(board.cbegin(), board.cend(), [](PIECE p){return p == PIECE::EMPTY;}) << std::endl;
```

Output:

> true
>   false

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess: Try a difference template parameter for VALUE and for the element type of VECTOR.

I don't use MSVC so I'm not sure exactly what error you're getting.

... regardless of all that, I just have to repeat my comment: Please don't write this kind of code.

Answer (score 1):

Although the solution using `std::any_of` is the best one, I give my answer that show somewhat less drastic improvement to original code.

```
template <typename T, typename Checker>
bool check_for_each(const T& v, const Checker condition)
{
    return condition(v);
}

template <typename T, typename Checker>
bool check_for_each(const std::vector<T>& v, const Checker condition)
{
    return std::find_if(begin(v), end(v), [condition](const T &t) { return check_for_each(t, condition); }) != v.end();
}

template <typename T, typename U>
bool is_equal_any(const T& value, const U &container)
{
    return check_for_each(container, [&value](const T& val){ return value == val; });
}

enum class PIECE_NAME { EMPTY, PAWN, ROOK, KNIGHT, BISHOP, QUEEN, KING };

void test()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<PIECE_NAME>> board
    { 
        { PIECE_NAME::ROOK, PIECE_NAME::BISHOP },
        { PIECE_NAME::KNIGHT, PIECE_NAME::QUEEN } 
    };
    std::cout << is_equal_any(PIECE_NAME::ROOK, board);
}
```

This solution is still hard-coded for nested vectors but the code has been simplified a bit and also optimized as it will stop searching once an item is found.

As already suggested in other comments, you should really use `enum` (or better yet `enum class`). It does not make much sense to store integers in the vector as you loose type information.